# Force bash to respect newlines in command output

Tags: bash

When I run `ls *` its returning entries delimited by a newline. However my shell is ignoring the newlines to condense the output. I would like each entry on a separate line.

**Currently:**

```
> ls *
a b c
```

**Ideally:**

```
> ls *
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-1` option:

`ls -1 *`

I just found that out today, too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/733152/ls-output-not-compact-anymore

I wanted to do the exact opposite...